# consume json data in angularjs from node.js as backend and sql db

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I am designing a simple application which has node.js server on the backend and angularjs on front. I am using code like this for a simple `GET` request to fetch some information from `sqldb`:

```
req.execute('view_proc').then(function (recordsets) {
            if (recordsets) {
                res.write(JSON.stringify(recordsets));
                console.log(recordsets);
                result_send = {
                    is_logged: true,
                };
```

I'am sending the data to angularjs using json.stringify. The following is the get request in angularjs:

```
$http.get('/api/views/123').success(function(data,status,headers,config){

}).
  error(function(data,status,headers,config){

});
```

I want to know how the JSON data to be consumed in angularjs and also want the json data to be displayed in angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't hard at all. Data, received from the server is stored in `data` variable, inside of the callback function:

```
$http.get('/api/views/123').success(function(data,status,headers,config){
  console.log(data)  //--> logs out the data to the console
})
```